# How do I transitively forward requirements via an IMPORTED CMake target?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create an alias called `OpenSSL::Crypto` to the target `crypto` that already exists. So far I have the following in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(OpenSSL::Crypto STATIC IMPORTED)
target_link_libraries(OpenSSL::Crypto INTERFACE crypto)
...
add_executable(my_test ...)
target_link_libraries(my_test OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

Generation works ok, but during compilation I get the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/build.make:82: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

and at `build.make:82`:

```
my_test: OpenSSL::Crypto-NOTFOUND
```

Why doesn't this work? My expectation is that all required target properties would be transitively picked up from `crypto`. What am I missing?

**Notes:**

- If I declare a dependency directly to `crypto` (`target_link_libraries(my_test crypto)`) everything works as expected.
- I can't use an `ALIAS` library because they don't propagate in other projects (as needed by my dependencies using `try_compile`).
- The background is I'm trying to use LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL by including it as a subdirectory in my project and allowing all other dependencies to build against it.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: `IMPORTED` library target implies that the library has `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property. So linking with the library would mean (among other things) passing library file to the linker. If you do not want to set this property, use `INTERFACE` library target instead.

Comment: Sadly names with `::` are not allowed for `INTERFACE` libraries. Do you know a workaround for that?

Comment: I got this to work by using the (apparently undocumented) variant `add_library(OpenSSL::Crypto INTERFACE IMPORTED)`

Comment: @DanNestor If you found a solution that works, consider writing up a quick Answer post to explain and demonstrate what fixed the issue for you. It will benefit future visitors of your question!

Comment: Thanks, I will, as soon as I'm certain it's answer-worthy ;)